# Removing data from loop and saving to a file

Tags: python-2.7, loops, save

I have two loops which have two variables each.
`cutoff1` and `cutoff2` contain measured data, and `BxTime` and `ByTime`contain time data from 0 to 300 s (It was used to set up scale in matplotlib). I have used this loop:

```
Loop = zip(BxTime,cutoff1)
for tup in Loop:
    print (tup[0], tup[1])

Loop2 = zip(ByTime,cutoff2)
for tup in Loop2:
    print (tup[0], tup[1])
```

It prints in my PyCharm enviroment a vertical list of measurements and time of their occurence, first from `Loop`, then from `Loop2`. My question here is a bit complex, because I need to:

1. Save this loops to a file which will write my data vertically. First column `cutoff1` second column `BxTime`, third column `cutoff2` forth column `ByTime`.
2. Second, after or before step 1, I need to erase concrete measurements. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
def writeData(fileName, tups):

    '''takes a filename, creates the file blank (and deletes existing one)
    and a list of 2-tuples of numbers. writes any tuple to the file where
    the second value is > 100'''

    with open(fileName,"w") as f:
        for (BxTime,cutoff1) in tups:
            if cutoff1 <= 100:
               continue  # goes to the nex tuple
            f.write(str(BxTime) + '\t' + str(cutoff1) + "\n" )`



Loop = zip(BxTime,cutoff1)
# for tup in Loop:
#    print (tup[0], tup[1])

Loop2 = zip(ByTime,cutoff2)
# for tup in Loop2:
#     print (tup[0], tup[1])

writeData('filename1.csv', Loop)
writeData('filename2.csv', Loop2)
```

I have used that code, but:

1. There are still measurements which contain 100.0
2. Before saving to a file I have to wait till the whole loop is printed, how to avoid that?
3. Is there any other way to save it to a text file instead of csv, which later open as Excel?

Comment: Here I need to focus on `cutoff1` and `cutoff2`. Those variables contain measured data, and they start from 100.0 up to even 3000.0 pT. I have cut off all values below 100.0 pT so now it works as 0 on my matplotlib scale. So, let's make it other way, let us make two tables one for `cutoff1` and second for `cutoff2`, save them without all measurements equal to 100.0 pT.

Comment: Remove because I need a file (or two files doesn't really matter) which collect  a vertical list of all measurements above 100.0 with the information of time occurence, taken from `BxTime` or `ByTime` depending on concrete variable (`cutoff1` for `BxTime` or `cutoff2` for `ByTime`).

Comment: Adding `<=100:` Helped, also changing from `.csv` to `.txt` helped. There is a problem with printing both loops, adding `#` makes an error in the code. I'm sure you have better idea how to improve my code (below UPDATE) line in my question. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Reformatted your code. Commented the print-statementst. As for ideas: study python. SO is for questions with answers. Edits to questions that respecify and respec and add on and adjust and .... - is not what we do. Pyhton is really simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def writeData(fileName, tups):

    '''takes a filename, creates the file blank (and deletes existing one)
    and a list of 2-tuples of numbers. writes any tuple to the file where
    the second value is >= 100'''

    with open(fileName,"w") as f:
        for (tim,dat) in tups:
            if dat < 100:
               continue  # goes to the nex tuple
            f.write(str(tim) + '\t' + str(dat) + "\n" ) # adapt to '\r\n' for windows
```

Use it like this:

```
writeData("kk.csv", [(1,101),(2,99),(3,200),(4,99.999)])
```

Output:

```
1   101
3   200
```

Should work with your zipped `Loop` and `Loop2` of (time, data).

You might need to change the line-end from `'\n'` to `'\r\n'` on windows.

Comment: `def writeData(fileName, tups):


    with open(fileName,"w") as f:


        for (BxTime,cutoff1) in tups:


            if cutoff1 < 100:


               continue  # goes to the nex tuple


            f.write(str(BxTime) + '\t' + str(cutoff1) + "\n" )`



It looks like this, but nothing has been saved cause I am missing something,

Comment: No. simple copy the function as is and call it:  `writeData('filename1.csv', Loop)` and `writeData('filename2.csv', Loop2)` with the `Loop`s defined as above